# How were sundials first divided up into hour-long segments?

Tags: astronomy, time

Even with present-day knowledge of celestial mechanics, if you asked me to go outside and set up a sundial without the aid of any other timekeeping devices, I would have a very hard time. The time between sun-up and sun-down vary from day to day, so even though I could draw a mark at noon (the time when the shadows are the shortest), I would be unable to figure out how big to make the hour sections. How did people mark out the hours on the first sundials?

I imagine that I could wait for an equinox, mark sun-up and sun-down, and then divide that in to twelve equal segments, but without a clock I don't see how I could prove that the day and night of the equinox were indeed of equal length.

Comment: Is there a sundial near you that you can look at?  I seem to recall that the 12 segments are in fact not equal.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar It depends on how the sundial is constructed. If it is oriented in a certain way the segments can be equal, but if it is on the ground or hung on a wall they may be unequal. Putting the sundial directly in the Sun's plane makes this problem as easy as possible.

Comment: You don't need to measure time at all to find the equinox. It occurs on those two days in which the Sun rises and sets at exactly opposite directions - East, West.

Comment: @Chrystomath Would an ancient have been able to know that the day and night are equal in duration when that happens?

Comment: I don’t know the answer to your question, but Anaximander is credited with the invention of the gnomon; perhaps you could start there.

Comment: The Greeks realised, probably through mathematics, that when sunrise and sunset are opposite in direction, then the day and night are equal. But it could be that the Babylonians knew this too.